# C - debug memory issue

Tags: c, memory

I'm new to C and I'm getting unexpected values the second time a function is called.

I don't understand why this is happening since I'm allocating new memory for `method`, `target` and `version`.

```
first run:
GET / HTTP/1.1
method: 'GET', target: '/', version: 'HTTP/1.1'

second run:
GET / HTTP/1.1
method: 'GET�1', target: '/�1', version: 'HTTP/1.1��1'
```

code:

```
bool parse(const char* line, char* abs_path, char* query)
{
    char* method = malloc(LimitRequestLine + 1);
    char* target = malloc(LimitRequestLine + 1);
    char* version = malloc(LimitRequestLine + 1);

    // iterate over chars from line and set method, target and version respectively
    for (int i = 0, j = 0, part = 0, n = strlen(line); i < n; i++) {
        if (line[i] == ' ') {
            part++;
            j = 0;
            continue;
        } else if (line[i] == '\r' || line[i] == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        if (part == 0)
                method[j] = line[i];
        else if (part == 1)
                target[j] = line[i];
        else if (part == 2)
                version[j] = line[i];
        j++;
    }
    printf("method: '%s', target: '%s', version: '%s'\n", method, target, version);

    ...

}
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm allocating and writing to this memory here which could explain how these extra characters are appended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must terminate strings by adding null character.

In this case, using `calloc()` is an easy way.

```
char* method = malloc(LimitRequestLine + 1);
char* target = malloc(LimitRequestLine + 1);
char* version = malloc(LimitRequestLine + 1);
```

should be

```
char* method = calloc(LimitRequestLine + 1, sizeof(char));
char* target = calloc(LimitRequestLine + 1, sizeof(char));
char* version = calloc(LimitRequestLine + 1, sizeof(char));
```

Comment: or `memset (method, 0, LimitRequestLine+1)` etc... after each `malloc` - same principle. Have to admit, never thought of using `calloc` as an alternative.

Comment: `calloc()` will "initialise" all allocated bytes to 0, which is unnecessary, making the program slower.

Comment: @sunqingyao I said "an easy way". Adding `'\0'`before updating `part` and breaking the loop may be better for performance, but you will have to write relatively long code.